# How to copy large datasets from one data source to another in Oracle(SqlDeveloper) / MS Sql Server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

Using C#,
I have tried using BulkCopy and BulkInsert in the batches of 5000. But for 300million rows it is still taking lots of time and memory. Gives **Out of Memory Exception.**
For bulk copying:

1. We get data from source.
2. We upload it to target.

Is there a way where I can copy from one datasource to another datasource in the table with same name without loading any data?(if table does not exists, then create a new one)

(without loading data data meaning: without getting data first)
I want to copy all the rows directly from source to target through code in C#.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Just use an tool specifically designed to do ETL.

Comment: Obviously, you cannot move the data without actually moving the data. Two arbitrary databases know nothing about each other and they do not have any way to exchange the data without *something* that knows both. If you may connect one database to the other, you may use database link or openrowset to query remote data and insert it locally.

Comment: Even if you *have to* use C# for some reason, it's certainly not the case that moving a large amount of data means you will necessarily run out of memory. Surely you are filling some kind of buffer object in c# and *reusing that buffer*, right? You're not just storing *all* data that passes through the C# code in some C# collection object for the entire duration of the execution, are you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ssis to extract transform and load data from any source to another, install sql server data tools from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16
then you can create ssis package deploy on sql server and use it in your application